# @-moz-document and @media together

Tags: css, media-queries

How can I combine above prefixes? This doesn't work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {

    @-moz-document url-prefix()   { 
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand  {margin-left:30%;}
    }
}
```

And `@media` inside of `@-moz-document url-prefix()` also deosn't work.

Answer (score 6):

It works fine for me by using the `@-moz-document` at first and the `@media` query inside:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand  {margin-left:30%;}
    }
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfxdndw9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Every pseudo-element must be valid within a rule, otherwise the whole rule is dropped.

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document, and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#rule-sets